# Chance number of digits on the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, digits, x-axis

I try to plot price agains year. year is formated as integer, but is ploted with one digit. How can I change that? x-axis without digit.

df looks like this:

[image]

now I use this code to plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Jahr, Energiepreis)) + geom_line()
```

plot looks like this

[image]

I tried with `scale_x_continous()` but with no success so far

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide your data using `dput()`? Please avoid posting images of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `ggplot2` will choose approx. 5 breaks for a continuous variable, which quite often works fine but as your values are years I would opt for setting the desired breaks explicitly using the `breaks` argument, e.g. to add a break for every second year you could do:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Jahr = 2020:2030,
  Energiepreis = 1:11
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Jahr, Energiepreis)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2020, 2030, 2))
```

[image]